Heading and Subheading numbering issue
I am writing an IEEE journal paper and downloaded the format in latex. Now the issue is that in the IEEE journal paper, the Headings are denoted by I,II,III and while subheading with A, B,C and so on.
Now the issue is that under one of my heading , there are 30 subheading, till 26 we have Z, after that Alphabet missing I tried everything but the template is not adding the AA, AB,AC in the subheadings.
III. Methodlogy
A. Equipment
B. Quantities
......
.....
.....
Z. Measurements
AA. Ingredients
AB. Sizes

I have use
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\alphalph{\value{subsection}}}

in some other document and its working fine, but same line doesn't work in IEEE template, I am stuck please help me out.

As always on this site, you're much more likely to get any help if you provide a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is. Did you load the package that provides \alphalph? This is one of the reasons why we always ask for the example.

A closely related posting (but not an exact duplicate): Do subsections have limits in the IEEEtran document class?

You were close. Assuming you're using the IEEEtran document class without the compsoc option, you need to run
\usepackage{alphalph}
\renewcommand\thesubsectiondis{\AlphAlph{\value{subsection}}.}


Addendum: If your document has a table of contents, you should also run \renewcommand\thesubsection{\AlphAlph{\value{subsection}}.

yes this works thankyou so much
